# Is current action a ChildAction?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How can I determine if current action is a ChildAction or routed main action? Should I check the URL and compare to the action's name? That's not so nice, since it's dependent on routing patterns...
Or should I make two actions of the same name, put a ChildActionOnly on one of them and have separate logic (mainly returning View() or PartialView())? How will the overloads be differentiated?

Okay, from an other perspective: How to make it so, that if it's a ChildAction then return a PartialView, otherwise a full View?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You could use the [`IsChildAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllercontext.ischildaction.aspx) property:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (ControllerContext.IsChildAction)
    {
         // The Index action was invoked as child action using 
         // @Html.Action("index")
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Same thing inside view to return partialview
`if (Html.ViewContext.IsChildAction)
{
    Layout = null;
}`